# I can't read my JSON in my application

Tags: java, android, json

Actually i want to make a MCQ for a medical application in Android ! So i want to get question and my possible choice from my database but i have a problem when i try to get my question witch him choice. My error is showed by the JSONException and i don't know why :(

I check my JSON with jsonlint.com so i think it's ok for that.
Here is my JSON :

```
{
    "QCM": {
        "1": {
            "question": "Est-ce que Captain America gagne contre IronMan",
            "id": "31"
        },
        "2": {
            "choix": "Oui"
        },
        "3": {
            "choix": "Non"
        }
    }
}
```

and here is my JAVA from my Android application.

```
try {
                        JSONObject lesQuestions = response.getJSONObject("QCM");
                        Iterator<?> keys = lesQuestions.keys();

                        while(keys.hasNext()) {
                            String key = (String) keys.next();

                            if (lesQuestions.get(key) instanceof JSONObject) {
                                JSONObject obj = (JSONObject) lesQuestions.get(key);
                                String signesCliniques = obj.getString("question");
                                String choix = obj.getString("choix");
                                lesChoixButton.setText(choix);
                                symptomesQuestions.setText(signesCliniques);

                            }
                        }
                    }
```

i hope you can help me !

Comment: What's the exception? Can you post your logs?

Comment: Did u debug? What's the content in lesQuestions ?

Comment: Oh sorry, it's just say "org.json.JSONException: No Value For choix".
And i don't know how to use the debug :/ did u have a good tutorial ^^?

Comment: Looks like you should be using `response.getJSONArray("QCM");` rather than `response.getJSONObject("QCM");`. You also need to check if "question" exists using `obj.isNull("question")`

Comment: When i use a JSONArray, he say i can't use JSONArray for a JSONObject. When i didn't try to get the choix but only the question, i can get the question sucessfully. But when i try to get both of them, it show me "org.json.JSONException: No Value For choix".

Comment: Please check @ccsnoopy answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not every `JSONObject` in your JSON data has "question" and "choix" key. I am quite sure that you are getting `org.json.JSONException: No value for ......`

Make sure to check if there is "question" or "choix" parameter before you attempt to access it.

**EDIT:**

To check, you can use `JSONObject.has(String parameter)` or `JSONObject.isNull(String parameter)` method. Link: http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#has(java.lang.String)

Comment: Nice catch @ccsnoopy.

Comment: It would be better if he'd change the structure of his JSON though.

Comment: yes I agree, the structure could be better. e.g. separate answers and questions maybe.

Comment: Yeah, i'm actually getting the error "org.json.JSONException: No Value For choix" but when i'm only trying to get "question" it work, that's why i don't undertand, so according to you, i'm not getting parameter, but how can i check that ?

Comment: and actually your crash is when you are accessing this JSON: `"1": {
            "question": "Est-ce que Captain America gagne contre IronMan",
            "id": "31"
        },`, there is no "choix", hence the crash..

Comment: Okay, so yeah your right. My "Choix" have the question for value. so my JSON is not good !

Comment: Yes, you should really consider separating the questions and answers :)

Comment: How can i do that ? create two array in my php and encode them ?

Comment: Just made this out of nowhere. I think this is a good structure for your JSON:
{
    "QCM": {
        "question": "Est-ce que Captain America gagne contre IronMan",
        "id": "31",
        "choix": [
              "Oui", "Non"
          ]
        }
}

Comment: You can do that. Or you can create something like: {"QCM":{"question":{...}, {"answers":{"your array of answers"}}. edit: @trigger's answer makes more sense haha :D

Comment: I don't know how to do that, i'm trying to make the same Json but i can't :(

Comment: Can someone explain me how to make the same JSON from trigger ?

Comment: What are you using to create the json?

Comment: i get my json from my php with query to database

Answer (score 0):

I suggest changing the structure of your JSON. Having a JSONObject for the question and a JSONArray for the Choices. Still up to you though if you still want to proceed with your current implementation. What you could try to use is [JSON.optString()](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#optString(java.lang.String)). It would return a value depending if the key exists, else it will return an empty string. As per its description:

> Returns the value mapped by name if it exists, coercing it if necessary, or the empty string if no such mapping exists.

Use it like so, change your:

```
String choix = obj.getString("choix");
```

to

```
String choix = obj.optString("choix");
```

It should work. You can make it better though.

Comment: Hi,
Thank for that but it didn't solve my problem, when i do that, i can only acess to my "Choix" but not in my question, it can read choix but not question.

Comment: I just used the `String choix` as a sample. Use it also for your `String signesCliniques`.

Comment: it's what i did, it didn't show my question but only my choice :(

Answer (score 0):

The Correct answer is,  first when you get your response from your server, parse/convert it into JSONObject like

```
 JSONObject rootObject = new JSONObject (response.toString());
```

and Then follow your JSON parsing as you are doing. This will do for sure.

```
 JSONObject lesQuestions = rootObject.getJSONObject("QCM");
```

Answer (score 0):

Android `JSON` parsers provide another optional method which begins with "`opt`" in comparison to methods which begin with "`get`". The significance with `opt` is that, it will return a `NULL` result and not `throw` an `exception`.

E.g:

`obj.getString("question");` will `throw` an `exception` if the `JSON` does not have a key with value "`question`."

However,

`String s = obj.optString("question");` will **NOT** `throw` an `exception` if the `JSON` does not have a key with value "`question`". Your result string will simply be `NULL`.

I find the `opt` methods very handy rather than the `get` methods which `throws` `exceptions`.